# Setup and build Jenkins project in sub-directory level

Tags: jenkins

I recently installed and configured Jenkins with Bitbucket in order to build and test a Bitbucket project that is inside a sub-directory. I wanted to test project inside a directory instead from master branch of Bitbucket because I would like to start from small and make sure not other projects are affected. I would like to know if there is any way to build a project in Jenkins from a sub-directory of Bitbucket instead from Master Branch. For example I want to build only sub directory 2;

```
*/master
 - Directory 1
    - sub directory 1
          -pom.xml
          - sub directory 2
               - pom.xml

 - Directory 2
    - sub directory A
          -  subdirectory B
                - pom.xml
```

Comment: you can, of course, execute commands in sub-directories, yes. What's the actual problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have been trying building a project only from a sub-directory in Jenkins but Jenkins build everything from master branch including other projects from other directories as well. I am not sure how to configure Jenkins to get the job done. I tried adding relative path to the sub-directory inside Additional Behaviour with "Check out to a sub-directory" option inside Source Code Management but Jenkins does not build as I expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
"Additional Behaviours" -> "Sparse Checkout paths"

But you need to have recent version of Git, at least above 1.7.10